# jQuery Does not work until hitting Page Refresh

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC web app using C#.  Everything works fine until I perform an "SAVE" action.  This Actions

reads data from the page

i.e

```
 x = $("#mytextbox").val();
```

x is always the initial value that was populated when the page loaded. It does not return the value the user key in after the page loaded.  I also noticed that the jquery in this SAVE function does perform the jQuery show/hide ex:

```
 $("#messagebox").show(); -- to show the user the feedback for the save action.
```

Now. If I hit F5 or refresh the page. all the above works fine.

Could it be that the html elements I add to the div is not in the DOM?

This block of code is in my .ascx (partial view)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $("#save-button").button(); -- Works
    $("#status-button").button(); -- Works
    $("#DateField").datepicker(); --Works
    alert($("#DebugtextBox").val()); --Works

    $("#DebugtextBox").val("test"); -- Works but does not update the val in the html page
    alert($("#DebugtextBox").val()); -- Works and shows "TESTS" in the alert. But the field in html page still shows the original val.
```

// more infor on the line above.. this

Comment: You're going to have to show us a trivial example that demonstrates this problem. Clearly, this isn't how most MVC applications work. Also, which version of MVC?

Comment: maybe your javascript is cached .. in your script reference try to add a ?v=1.1 example yourjavascript.js?v=1.1  that will force the latest version of your script to be loaded

Comment: I dont think it is related to MVC. I suspect it is mainly js and jquery..

Comment: If F5 fixes the issue - then it means that page before and after isn't the same.

Comment: If the js is cached then it should work once it got working... this has a consistent behavior...

Comment: @magic-c0d3r I agree but that is just strange

Comment: I would try wrapping all your js inside of a DOM load event `$(document).ready(function(){ /* code here */ });`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was having multiple textboxes with the same ID.